# File download rename not working

Tags: html, google-chrome

I try to rename file with download attribute but it's not working.

```
<a href="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" download="something.png">OK</a>
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jvx31ta3/1/)

Comment: What are you trying to .append to?

Comment: the problem is not in append.

Comment: Okay, what is the type of file you are wishing to download / rename?

Comment: Is there a `Content-Disposition` header in the response that specifies a file name?  Maybe that takes priority over the `download` attribute's  value.

Comment: @MikeSav it depend but mostly .rar

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/csdz89fa/

Comment: @APAD1 This didn't seem to work when I tried using an actual link to a file (same file type specified) https://jsfiddle.net/cs5gtaLe/

Comment: @AndrewBrooke yes that's my problem

Comment: @AndrewBrooke that's because it doesn't work for external files

Comment: @David i don't specify any headers.

Comment: @Youssef: Can you demonstrate that?  In your browser's debugging tools, capture the headers of the response.  That would definitely make for some helpful information to add to the question.

Comment: @David what response ? because i load a page and after i add the anchor element. you want the reponse of the first page before i add element to it ?

Comment: @Youssef: The response which contains the file that's being downloaded.  You know, when you click on the link to download it.

Comment: @David nothing happened on network tab of chrome's debugging tools when i click on the link to download it.

Comment: @Youssef: Then how is the file actually being downloaded?  I suspect you're missing something.

Comment: @David i use `tampermonkey` to create a script on web site so to automatize downloading i use my own script to download files on that web site

Comment: @Youssef: That's nice.  But what you have in the question is simply an `a` tag which has a link to a file.  When you click that link, the file is downloaded, yes?  Then clearly the browser is *requesting a file* and *receiving a response*.  You're going to want to capture that response.  Because currently the most reasonable answer is that the response contains a header which specifies the file name.  If that's not the case, you'll need to demonstrate that.

Comment: @David the problem is that the download open a new tab but quickly close it when the download is starting.

Comment: _"the problem is that the download open a new tab but quickly close it when the download is starting."_ Can create jsfiddle to demonstrate ? _"rename not working"_ User should still have option to rename file at "Save File" dialog ?

Comment: The reason why your jsfiddle is not working is becuse the origion is not the same, the sandboxed result runs in `fiddle.jshell.net` and the resource you are trying to download is on `jsfiddle.net`

Comment: you are right @Endless but how to solve it ?

Comment: @Youssef see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33830576/1008999) just below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It only works if the file is on the same origin so if you can download a external file with CORS + ajax then you can save the blob with a custom name

```js
$('a').click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    var name = this.download;
   
    // we need a blob so we can create a objectURL and use it on a link element
    // jQuery don't support responseType = 'blob' (yet)
    // So I use the next version of ajax only avalible in blink & firefox
    // it also works fine by using XMLHttpRequest v2 and set the responseType
    fetch("https://crossorigin.me/" + this.href)
        // res is the beginning of a request it only gets the response headers
        // here you can use .blob() .text() .json or res.arrayBuffer() depending
        // on what you need, if it contains Content-Type: application/json
        // then you might want to choose res.json() 
        // all this returns a promise
        .then(res => res.blob())
        .then(blob => {
            $("<a>").attr({
                download: name,
                href: URL.createObjectURL(blob)
            })[0].click();
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" download="something.png">OK</a>
```

Comment: it works but it took a little bit time and i will left using CORS proxy like `crossorigin.me` as final choice.

Comment: i use `fetch("https://crossorigin.me/" + this.href)` without `https://crossorigin.me/` like this `fetch( this.href)` and it works can you explain me why ?

Comment: I just added crossorigin.me cuz i didn't know if the resource you are trying to fetch is already CORS enabled .. so the file maybe already had `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` response header

Comment: with CORS enabled, you are able to read the content from another source with javascript

Comment: thanks man for the help. just if you want explain me the fetch thing and `blob` and `res` i would appreciate that.

Comment: @Youssef to much expelling of the fetch api. long story short. its next version of ajax. fetch first makes what almost is a HEAD request to only fetch the response headers and then continues to download the rest of the data once you decide how you want to receive it. i choosed blob (the equivelent of `responseType = 'blob'` in `XMLHttpRequest` v2) b/c i needed to create an objectURL in order to download it with a href. Here is one awesom article [that is so fetch](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/thats-so-fetch/) I didn't use jQuery ajax method b/c it dosen't suport `responseType = 'blob'`

Answer (score 5):

From the docs you linked:

> If the HTTP header Content-Disposition: is present and gives a different filename than this attribute, the HTTP header has priority over this attribute.

My guess is that the server you're linking to sets this header.

Also if you're linking to an external resource it likely won't work:

> This attribute is only honored for links to resources with the same-origin.

Comment: how to override the priority if `Content-Disposition` is present ? because i think this is my problem because links to resources are with the same-origin.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this attribute doesn't work anymore for external files, due to possible security concerns.

You can find a discussion about this issue for Chrome [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=373182)

> Use of the 'download' attribute will always trigger a download, but **from M-35 onwards will only honor the suggested filename if the final resource URL is same-origin as the document.** Even when it doesn't, as long as a MIME type is specified correctly, it will receive a filename like 'download.' where  is the extension known to the host OS as mapping to the specified MIME type. If the resource is served with a Content-Disposition, then the Content-Disposition will take precedence.

And for Firefox [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=874009) and [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676619)